# Image Uploader doesn't allow pasting in an animated gif image

Tags: feature-request, uploader

Most images I can copy with right click, and then paste onto the image uploader - I don't have to save then browse for it.

However, I can't paste animated gif images into the image uploader - it shows, uploads and inserts just the first frame.

To clarify, I can upload an animated gif image, and it inserts it fine, but I just can't *paste* it in.

Comment: So, you _can_ upload gifs? Are you talking about animated gifs? Can you please clarify, as what you posted seems to be a bit self contradictory.

Comment: @Oded I can upload them if they are saved, but not paste it into it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean about "first frame"? Is paste working fine with single frame gifs or not at all? Is the issue simply with animated gifs on paste?

Comment: @Oded simply animated gifs - it inserts it as a png image not a gif image.